# (WPF) Rotate Grid with storyboard on MouseDown

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So recently I asked how to rotate a stackpanel with the Button.Click-event
But now I have to do the same thing, but with a Grid and with the MouseDown-event
So basically, when I click the grid, this has to rotate 180°.

I don't exactly know if this is possible with a storyboard-element?
That's why I'm asking you guys.

The following code is simply the XAML file, there's no code behind because I have no idea how to pull this off.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="pnlFlip" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Grid Height="317">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="btnTest" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation To="180" Storyboard.TargetName="pnlFlip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"  />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="rectTest" Fill="Red" Height="127"/>
    </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Now I know there's a button there, but that's because I have no clue how to do this.
So when a user clicks the grid, the animation would have to work.

Is there a way to kind of simulate a button click event on mouse down to trigger it?

Comment: The issue is that I cannot create a storyboard in the XAML file for a <Grid.Triggers></Grid.Triggers>
Or how do I have to do this? I'm kinda new to WPF.
Could you explain with some code/examples what you exactly mean?

Comment: Sorry, last time I tried I typed Tirggers, that's why it didn't work. Thanks for the answer, pretty straightforward .. one stupid typo messed everything up last time :p

Comment: Great. I posted that solution and ignored the typo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your trigger to the `Grid` and go off of the `MouseDown` event:

```
<Grid.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.MouseDown">
...
    </EventTrigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
```